# isset and GET with Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm working with Laravel. Trying to work out the best conversion for below. Would I use query builder or eloquent and where should I integrate the code (view, controller, model), here is how I would perform normally:

HTML - *GET records with /sweden or /stockholm - (.htaccess urls)*

```
<a href="retailers/country/sweden">Sweden</a>
<a href="retailers/city/stockholm">Stockholm</a>
```

PHP - *Grab the the data connected with those records*

```
if (isset($_GET['country']) || isset($_GET['city'])) 
{   
$country = $_GET['country'];
$store = $_GET['city'];
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from table WHERE country = ? or city = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($country, $city));
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :

//output stuff

endwhile

} else { //do something else }
```

Here is how my current Laravel pattern looks:

Model:

```
class DataListings extends Eloquent {
    public $table ='database';
}
```

Controller:

```
public function data() {
return View::make('data')
->with('table', DataListings::all())
}
```

Here is my **view** and how I am presuming I would put this together and this is where I am getting confused. What goes where, does the  `if (isset()` go in my controller, model or here in the view? do I use query builder or elequent? If I could get an example on how to convert the above, it would be great.

```
@if 

@foreach($table as $data) // this here is my while :
{{ $data->country }}, etc etc
@endforeach

@else
//do something else
@endif
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use the `$_GET` superglobal, as Laravel provides an interface for accesing request params. Use `Input::get('country');` and  `Input::get('city');` If you want to check that they are set, use `Input::has('country');` http://laravel.com/docs/requests

Comment: It's all SELECT and queries, see my above example. I just need to know how to convert the above into Laravel, could you give me an example, using the above as template etc.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I thought the code was already in Laravel. That said, if you are converting it to Laravel, it's better to use `Input` for accessing values in $_GET, $_POST, $_FILES, etc so I'd still recommend it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things are easier in Laravel than in pure PHP, you just create a route to process that request and you won't have to deal directly with the superglobal $_GET:

```
Route::get('retailers/{region}/{name}', function($region, $name) {

    $query = Table::newQuery();

    if ($region == 'country')
    {
        $query->where('country', $name);
    }
    else

    if ($region == 'city')
    {
        $query->where('city', $name);
    }

    return View::make('retailers.show')->with('table' => $query->get());

});
```

And in the cases where the URL doesn't have region and name, you can have a fallback route to get it:

```
Route::get('retailers', function() {

    return View::make('retailers.index');

});
```